# Compojure - how to return 404 when required params are not provided?

Tags: clojure, compojure

Suppose I have this handler:

```
(defroutes routes
  (DELETE    "/books"      [id]              (delete-book id)))
```

What can I do to make this app return HTTP 404 when request does not contain ID?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, you could make the `id` a part of the URI, which seems nice and RESTful and would allow you to use the route syntax to impose your condition:

```
(GET ["/books/:id" :id #"[0-9]+"] [] ...)
```

If you do prefer to use a parameter, something like

```
(if-not id
  (ring.util.response/not-found body-for-404)
  ...)
```

should work in the next Ring version, though this particular function has not been released yet (it simply returns `{:status 404 :headers {} :body the-body}` though).

Also,

```
(when id
  ...)
```

would result in the equivalent of a route match failure and the remaining routes would be tried; then you could use

```
(compojure.route/not-found body-for-404)
```

as the final route which would always match.

Finally, if you wish to apply filtering to a large group of Compojure handlers, you may wish to combine them into a single handler with Compojure's `defroutes` or `routes` (the latter is a function) and wrapping them in a piece of middleware:

```
(defn wrap-404 [handler]
  (fn wrap-404 [request]
    (when (-> request :params :id)
      (handler request))))
```

You can then include the wrapped handler as an entry in `routes` / `defroutes` forms.

Comment: Is there no way to do it automatically (e.g. with a param to the compojure macro)? Hate to do it for all routes.

Comment: I've edited the answer with some ways of DRYing things up. I'd go with the URI-based approach myself. There's no magic syntax to impose conditions on the actual contents of the params map in Compojure's DSL.